# What are the implications of modifying the Longitude of Origin?

Tags: coordinate-system

I do a lot of GIS work with Alaska data, much of which comes from the [State Geo-data Clearinghouse](http://www.asgdc.state.ak.us/) in EPSG: 3338 (NAD83 Alaska Albers), which has a longitude of false origin of -154.  Because Alaska is such a large area, making maps away from that longitude results in a skewed appearance where N, S, E, W lines are angled.  Here's an example from the northwest part of the state, using the default longitude value (-154) where the black lat/long lines are 68, -163:

[image]

In order to make such maps more pleasing to my audience, I often modify the CRS' longitude of false origin to match the longitude of the map center.  This can easily be done in either the QGIS *Project Properties* or ArcMap *Data Frame Properties*.  In the following example, I've changed the longitude of origin from the default -154 to match the map's -163:

[image]

I store the data, and do all analysis with the default CRS.  Modifying the latitude of origin is only done for final map production and display.

Obviously, the "non-square" effect occurs in other locations and with other CRSs.  I use Alaska for illustrative purposes.

AFAIK, there is no drawback to adjusting the longitude of origin for display.  To me, what I'm doing is akin to rotating a globe while I look at it, holding my eyes steady.  But still, is there something here that is cartographically improper?

Comment: There's a difference between a *false* origin and a central meridian; changing the false origin should not rotate the data. It's not *cartographically* improper, but it is improper from an IT standpoint to assert an SRID name when your data isn't actually in that spatial reference.

Comment: Good point about the word *false*.  I could swear that I saw the phrase *longitude of false origin* somewhere in the QGIS project properties.  But now I can't find it anywhere.  Huh.  I now disavow the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are free to select the central meridian that you like, but bear in mind that "Alaska Albers" is a projection that is exactly defined, so do not use that name when making maps with CM 163W, instead use "Albers 163W".
(Typo edited)